# Is it possible to filter mail sent to any of my plus-addresses in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I use plus-addresses for either testing, or spam. To the point where now I would like to auto-archive **all** mail sent to a plus address.

I've tried searching with:

```
to:(firstname.lastname+*@gmail.com) // this doesn't find anything
```

and

```
to:(firstname.lastname\+*@gmail.com) // this includes emails 
sent to "firstname.lastname@gmail.com"
```

Is it possible to capture *just* plus addressed emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use **+test** like: **myname+test@gmail.com**

then you can use:

```
to:(+test)
```

otherwise, you can't list all +masks at once

Answer (score 1):

This is just an educated guess, so take it with a grain of salt, but I doubt you will be able to build a filter that does what you need, since the plus character (`+`) is used as a *search operator* to find an exact match of a word (e.g. `+example` will find all emails that have the word “example” in them). At least not using a wildcard. You might be able to do it using some sort of regex, but you still need to build your regex expression using (all) your plus-addresses.

[image]

[Source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190).

Comment: I think I could achieve this with regex. `firstname\.lastname\+.*@gmail.com` <- this looks like it would work, to me. But I don't see a way to use regex in searches. Do I need to flip a toggle or use a different field or something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do it all the time. Very simple, just use the *deliveredto*-operator.

[image]

Comment: What is the catch all for this case though? i.e. I'm looking for ~`deliveredto:+*` (that is, *everything* that includes a "+"). When I try `deliveredto:+*` though, It also includes emails sent to my non-plussed email address.

Comment: Can you do it the other way around, filter out everything that is not sent to a plus-address? I think my answer deserves to be accepted as the correct answer to your original question. If you agree, please mark it that way.

Comment: I cannot come up with a way to make a reverse filter work. My original question asked how to catch **all** plus addresses and exclude emails sent to my non-plussed address (I actually use that example in my question). Your answer (so far) does not address that. If you are able to update your answer to solve my issue, I'm happy to mark it as accepted, though.

Comment: Doesn't deliveredto:user0@gmail.com not work? What happens? How about -deliveredto:user0@gmail.com (this should exclude your "main" address).